# Using DoCmd.OutputTo to export an Access query to multiple Excel files

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a query "myQuery" that returns more than 65,000 records, and as such, cannot be exported to one .xlsx file.

I'm attempting to break up this output to multiple files.

I'm still very much a beginner with VBA, but I've put the following together as best I can from research. This code is intended to iterate through the queried data, then output a new file for each 65,000 records.

```vb
Private Sub btnfrm1export_Click()

Dim outputFileName As String
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
Dim numFiles As Integer
Dim rs As String
Dim numr As Integer
Dim sql As String
Dim rec As Recordset

'Allows user to pick destination for files and gives value to sItem.

Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With dlgOpen
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

'Counts the records in myQuery to give the number of files needed to numFiles, assuming 60,000 records per file.
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("myQuery")
numFiles = Round(rec.RecordCount / 60000, 0)
numr = 1

' Changes the SQL of the query _vba in the current Database to select 60000 records from myQuery
rs = "SELECT TOP 60000 myQuery.* FROM myQuery"
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("_vba").sql = rs

'Defines SQL for clearing top 60000 (used in the following loop).
sql = "DELETE TOP 60000 myQuery.* FROM myQuery"

'Loops once to create each file needed    
Do While numFiles > 0

'Sets a file name based on the destination folder, the file number numr, and information from a combobutton cbo1 on Form frm1.
    outputFileName = sItem & "\" & Forms!frm1!cbo1 & "_Report_Pt" & numr & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xlsx"

'Outputs top 60000 of myQuery records to an excel file.
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "_vba", acFormatXLSX, outputFileName

    numFiles = numFiles - 1
    numr = numr + 1

'Deletes top 60000 from myQuery.
    CurrentDb.Execute sql

Loop

End Sub
```

However, I'm getting:

> Run-time error '2302': Microsoft Access can't save the output data to the file you've selected.

at `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "_vba", acFormatXLSX, outputFileName`

I do need this to be automated in vba and without pop-ups, etc. Any suggestions to make my code more efficient and proper is appreciated, but the REAL question is how to eliminate the error with DoCmd.OutputTo or make this work.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Since you are using DAO, I'm curious what value you get for 'rec.RecordCount' - that is usually not populated unless you MoveLast?

Comment: From Excel 2007 (xlsx), the row limit is increased to 1,048,576
Which Access version do you have? I'm quite sure that with a version  from 2010 up, you can bypass that limit.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, surprisingly, I get the correct result without MoveLast. (I inserted a `MsgBox` line to print `rec.RecordCount`.) I'm not experienced enough to have any explanation, though.

Comment: @kiks73 I have Access 2010. The error that I got before I tried looping for multiple files was that Access could not copy more than 65000 records, so (to my limited understanding) it's a clipboard/memory limitation.

Comment: What about using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet?

Comment: Would that require making a table form the query first? It appears that method only uses tables.

Comment: I think I found a solution (still tinkering, but you can see that it works).  So far I have tested by right-clicking on a table and exporting and by creating a query and right-clicking.  Here is a link to an explanation / workaround.  http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/cant-export-more-than-65000-rows-to-excel-2007/

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, this has to be an automated process for my use case.

Comment: Can you try to record a macro while performing the necessary steps? Then you have the VBA code.  My @#&*! Access 2010 just lost the Developer toolbar and I'm trying to get it back.

Comment: Is there a record a macro option for Access? Or is that just Excel? For some reason, I can't find it.

Comment: Using the Access Macro builder to find an appropriate solution, there only appears to be an ExportWithFormatting method.

Comment: Try this (change SpreadsheetTypeas needed): DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "your-query-name", outputFileName, True. I'm having *senior* moments re Developer Bar - there is none in Access.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Thanks for you continued support! I tried this syntax with the query and with a table `_temp` that I created in the DB from the query. I continue to get runtime error 3051, which is about permissions. I haven't had this problem using `DoCmd.OutputTo`. I also unsuccessfully tried creating the file (via Excel) for it to move to.

Comment: Ahhh! Seek and ye shall find!  I just used the VBA code found at this link and it works!  http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/01/export-large-access-tablequery-to-excel.html

Comment: Thanks, @WayneG.Dunn ! That is very helpful. I'm working on implementing the automatic saving as my file name and such, but this looks like it will definitely work for my application.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I'd be happy to mark you as the answerer if you put together a sumamry/explanation post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the subject line concerns trying to output multiple Excel files, the real issue is trying to create an Excel file from an Access table or query which contains more than 65,000 rows - by using VBA. If VBA is NOT a requirement, then you can export a query or table by right-clicking on the object name, selecting export, then Excel. DO NOT check the box for 'Export data with formatting...' and it will work.

The code shown below was found at: http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/01/export-large-access-tablequery-to-excel.html (Created By Christos Samaras) and will properly export a large table/query to Excel

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub Test()  
    'Change the names according to your own needs.
    DataToExcel "Sample_Table", "Optional Workbook Path", "Optional Target Sheet Name"

    'Just showing that the operation finished.
    MsgBox "Data export finished successfully!", vbInformation, "Done"    
End Sub 


Function DataToExcel(strSourceName As String, Optional strWorkbookPath As String, Optional     strTargetSheetName As String)

'Use this function to export a large table/query from your database to a new Excel workbook.
'You can also specify the name of the worksheet target.

'strSourceName is the name of the table/query you want to export to Excel.
'strWorkbookPath is the path of the workbook you want to export the data.
'strTargetSheetName is the desired name of the target sheet.

'By Christos Samaras
'http://www.myengineeringworld.net

Dim rst         As DAO.Recordset
Dim excelApp    As Object
Dim Wbk         As Object
Dim sht         As Object
Dim fldHeadings As DAO.Field

'Set the desired recordset (table/query).
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSourceName)

'Create a new Excel instance.
Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

On Error Resume Next

'Try to open the specified workbook. If there is no workbook specified
'(or if it cannot be opened) create a new one and rename the target sheet.
Set Wbk = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(strWorkbookPath)
If Err.Number <> 0 Or Len(strWorkbookPath) = 0 Then
    Set Wbk = excelApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set sht = Wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If Len(strTargetSheetName) > 0 Then
        sht.Name = Left(strTargetSheetName, 34)
    End If
End If

'If the specified workbook has been opened correctly, then in order to avoid
'problems with other sheets that might contain, a new sheet is added and is
'being renamed according to the strTargetSheetName.
Set sht = Wbk.Worksheets.Add
If Len(strTargetSheetName) > 0 Then
    sht.Name = Left(strTargetSheetName, 34)
End If

On Error GoTo 0

excelApp.Visible = True

On Error GoTo Errorhandler

'Write the headings in the target sheet.
For Each fldHeadings In rst.Fields
    excelApp.ActiveCell = fldHeadings.Name
    excelApp.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next

'Copy the data in the target sheet.
rst.MoveFirst
sht.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
sht.Range("1:1").Select

'Format the headings of the target sheet.
excelApp.Selection.Font.Bold = True
With excelApp.Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = -4108 '= xlCenter in Excel.
    .VerticalAlignment = -4108  '= xlCenter in Excel.
    .WrapText = False
    With .Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 11
    End With
End With

'Adjusting the columns width.
excelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Freeze the first row - headings.
With excelApp.ActiveWindow
    .FreezePanes = False
    .ScrollRow = 1
    .ScrollColumn = 1
End With
sht.Rows("2:2").Select
excelApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

'Change the tab color of the target sheet.
With sht
    .Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Range("A1").Select
End With

'Close the recordset.
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

Exit Function

Errorhandler:
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
Exit Function

End Function
```